# Nested output buffering with external class dependencies [please help]

Tags: php, output-buffering

Thanks in advance for any and all advice.

I have one file (content file) where an array is created like so:

```
$config['plugins']['BannerRotate'] = array(
    'container'    =>    'abroadView',
    'arrows'    =>    true,
    'auto'        =>    true,
    'speed'        =>    '15000',
    'width'        =>    '300px',
    'height'    =>    '220px',
    'tags'      =>    'slider'
);
```

Which in turn is picked up by the so-called 'template system' and the layout is rendered with the page (and that array) as the argument (pretty standard).

That array is then used by the template system to generate a new object like so:

```
if(isset($GLOBALS['config']['plugins'])){
    foreach($GLOBALS['config']['plugins'] as $plugin => $ary){
        $$plugin = new Ispweb_Plugindaemon(CURRENTSRV,getcwd().'/',
        $GLOBALS['config']['plugins'][$plugin],$plugin);
        // this statement is simply the result of the eval statement below
    }
}
```

So then, since the name of the plugin in this case is BannerRotate, the object is $BannerRotate (variable variable). I'm doing this so I can have multiple plugin objects per page. This object is then used to call the jQuery plugin using member function $BannerRotate->getJS(). These member function calls are located WITHIN the templating system (IMPORTANT).

If I call a member function inside the same file as the initial array [OUTSIDE THE TEMPLATING SYSTEM] (the file that I'm buffering in order to create the object in the first place), everything dies. This doesn't make sense to me because if I var_dump($BannerRotate), I get a full object. However, say in that content file I do $BannerRotate->printNoscript(), everything disappears and the object is never created. I then get a fatal error that I'm calling a member function of a non-object. THAT IS THE PROBLEM.

Here is what I'm doing within the templating system to buffer the content file (and create the object(s)):

```
ob_start();
include $core_page_content; // the content file (where initial array is)
if(isset($GLOBALS['config']['plugins'])){
    foreach($GLOBALS['config']['plugins'] as $plugin => $ary){
        $ins[] = $plugin;
    }
}
$t = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
foreach($ins as $in){
    $a = CURRENTSRV; // a,b,c,d are just making the eval statement more clean
    $b = getcwd().'/';
    $c = array();
    foreach($GLOBALS['config']['plugins'][$in] as $key => $value){
        $c[$key] = $value;
    }
    $d = $in;
    eval("\$$in = new Ispweb_Plugindaemon(\"$a\",\"$b\",\$c,\"$d\");");
    echo $$in;
}
include $core_page_content;
$page_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Does anyone know why I can access the object UNLESS I make a call to one of its member functions while inside the same file?

What can I do?

P.S. I know the setup is not ideal. There's nothing I can do about that.

Thanks!

**TL;DR** I'm creating an object in file A, with a variable from file B. I buffer file B to get the parameters to feed to file A, create the object, print it into another buffer and include file B in that buffer as well. If file B has a function call to the presumably created object, I get a fatal error: call to member function of non-object.

Additional Notes:

File B:

```
$config['plugins']['BannerRotate'] = array(
    'container'    =>    'abroadView',
    'arrows'       =>    true
);
// page content (XHTML)
```

File A:

```
ob_start();
$core_page_content = 'file_b';
include $core_page_content;
if(isset($config['plugins'])){
foreach($config['plugins'] as $plugin => $ary){
    $ins[] = $plugin;
}
ob_end_clean();
foreach($ins as $in){
    $$in = new Ispweb_Plugindaemon(CURRENTSRV,getcwd().'/',$config['plugins'][$in],$in);
}
include $core_page_content;
$page_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// later on in the file
include 'top.htm';
include $page_content;
include 'bot.htm';
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you get the error, and indicate exactly where the error is thrown?  Oh and `eval`-ing new objects into existence is just plain evil...

Comment: Yeah, I know eval is evil - I don't like using it. The code errors out if I do a $BannerRotate->printNoscript() inside file B (see TL;DR). And that's exactly where the error occurs - no object.

Comment: Can you post the code around it that's generating the error.  Text descriptions mean very little...  And you don't have to use eval... `$$in = new Ispweb_Plugindaemon($a, $b, $c, $d);` will work just fine (even though using variable variables is still pretty evil, but admittedly less evil than using `eval`)...

Comment: <div id="abroadView">
        <noscript>
            <?php $BannerRotate->printNoscript(); ?>
        </noscript>
    </div>

That's really it. That's what is throwing the error. I don't know what else to post in response to your request. The object exists in the file B scope unless I make a call to any of the object's member functions.

Comment: Why do you need eval() in this particular place anyway? Maybe I'm missing something but doesn't `$$in = new Ispweb_Plugindaemon("$a","$b",$c,"$d");` do the same thing (maybe even without the quotes)?

Comment: I strongly believe that the information needed to solve the problem is not included in the question (yet). My _guess_ is it's related to http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope . You have `include $core_page_content;` twice in the code. The first time apparently to create this `$config['plugins']['BannerRotate']` array and the second time to "execute" the template. Exactly how does this work?

Comment: I don't need eval in this instance. I had the same line that was produced from the eval'd code commented out and not reproduced in this post. Anyway, $core_page_content is included the first time in a buffer within a buffer. This is extraneous. However, upon more testing, more confusion is added because it turns out I can access public variables, but not public functions from file B (see TL;DR). If it were a problem with scope, I wouldn't be able to access the object at all. Since I can access public variables, but not public functions, there is some other problem.

Comment: @VolkerK
The first time I buffer it, I save the contents in a variable, run the 'build object' foreach statement, (after discarding the buffer contents), and while in the parent buffer print out the object instantiations. Then, I include the same file as before but this time I pass it to the template system. This method has its own problems, for instance, I can't declare any functions in the content files due to double-declaration. Maybe if there's another way that I can parse for a variable in a file, output the code to make that variable effective, and then include the file, I should dothat?

Comment: @wanovak: Sorry I don't get it. Can you show us a complete, maybe simplified yet working example of the whole process? It still _sounds_ odd if not wrong.

Comment: @VolkerK - I added the additional notes to the initial post. Thanks.

Comment: Still most likely a problem with http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope Is any part of the code you've shown us so far wrapped in a function/method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was [variable scope.](http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope)